# jQuery get clicked ID from jQuery appended data

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to allow for my website to have extras on customers products, i've been able to let jQuery add the new extra to the database via AJAX and then append the results to the HTML.

But I am having issues with the removal, such as if the customer changes their mind and no longer wants the extra.

This code adds the HTML with the data and remove button.

```
$.each(data.extras, function (k, o) {
  $('#insertExtras').append('<div id="'+k+'"><div class="col-md-1">'+k+':</div><div class="col-md-7"><strong>'+o.extraName+'</strong> ('+o.extraPriceRadio+o.extraPrice+')</div><div class="col-md-4"><a id="removeExtra'+k+'" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark ladda-button" data-style="expand-left"><span class="ladda-label">Remove</span></a></div></div><br /><br />');    
});
```

This is the button from the above:

```
<a id="removeExtra'+k+'" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark ladda-button" data-style="expand-left"><span class="ladda-label">Remove</span></a>
```

The id will have a number inside it like so: removeExtra0, removeExtra1, removeExtra2 etc

Now when I try and have jQuery get the button that was clicked, it does nothing!

```
$('a[id^="removeExtra"]').on('click', function() { 
  alert('clicked');
  console.log('Picked: '+ $(this).prop("id"));              
});
```

I just want the id of the button that was clicked. So I can slice it and use it to remove that row.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [event-delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamically added elements

```
$('#insertExtras').on('click','[id^="removeExtra"]',function(){
     console.log('Picked: '+ this.id);  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `.on` wrong way use it like

```
$(document).on('click','a[id^="removeExtra"]', function() { 
        alert('clicked');
        console.log('Picked: '+ $(this).prop("id"));                
    });
```

[**Read about .on**](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Thank you for your help, this work have worked but i went for the other option another user gave me, instead of $(document) but $('#insertExtras')

Comment: No problem. The aim of my answer was to tell you how `.on` operates

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the event listener after the add.

```
//first run the loop
$.each(data.extras, function (k, o) {
    $('#insertExtras').append('<div id="'+k+'"><div class="col-md-1">'+k+':</div><div class="col-md-7"><strong>'+o.extraName+'</strong> ('+o.extraPriceRadio+o.extraPrice+')</div><div class="col-md-4"><a id="removeExtra'+k+'" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark ladda-button" data-style="expand-left"><span class="ladda-label">Remove</span></a></div></div><br /><br />');    
});
// then you can add the listener
$('a[id^="removeExtra"]').on('click', function() { 
    alert('clicked');
    console.log('Picked: '+ $(this).prop("id"));                
});
```